# How to calculate a Forward Pass with matrix operations in PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have got an input x, layer 1 weight matrix, and layer 2 weight matrix.

Now I want to calculate the output of this pre-trained neural network via hand:

x * weights1 * weights2

While doing this I receive a RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (6) must match the size of tensor b (4) at non-singleton dimension 1

```
class Net(nn.Module):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4,6)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(6,2)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(2,1)

def forward(self, x):
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
    return x

net = Net()
X = torch.randn(1000,4)
net.fc2.weight*(net.fc1.weight * X[0])
```

Comment: Add a batch dimension to the input. See [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#linear) for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing element-wise multiplication (`*` operator) with matrix multiplication (`@` operator).
Try:

```py
net.fc2.weight @ (net.fc1.weight @ X[0])
```